# How can you get 1.7-compatible output for a java_proto_library?

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers, bazel

For a `java_library`, I can set the `javacopts` attribute on the build rule. There doesn't appear to be anything similar for `java_proto_library` or `java_lite_proto_library`.

I *can* work around this by setting `-source` and `-target` options to javac via the `-javacopt` flag to bazel, but I'd rather have it encoded in the BUILD files.

Comment: Are you sure it's not _already_ 1.7-compatible output anyway?

Comment: Ah I should have mentioned. Dropping the jar into an Android project resulted in dx complaining about the class file version. This didn't happen when building with the options set via `--javacopt` flag.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Java protos take additional javacopt from java_toolchain's undocumented compatible_javacopts, which is not populated in Bazel's //tools/jdk:toolchain. So, I think the compilation will not be 1.7 compatible. Should we modify the toolchain?

Comment: Filed https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2829

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a JDK7 toolchain and then build everything with it.  E.g., add [this](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_appengine/blob/e34819997d8a521cdb090e681a64f224304f4bd2/appengine/BUILD#L27-L46) to a BUILD file:

```
java_toolchain(
    name = "jdk7",
    bootclasspath = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:bootclasspath"],
    encoding = "UTF-8",
    extclasspath = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:extdir"],
    genclass = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:GenClass_deploy.jar"],
    header_compiler = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:turbine_deploy.jar"],
    ijar = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:ijar"],
    javabuilder = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:JavaBuilder_deploy.jar"],
    javac = ["@bazel_tools//third_party/java/jdk/langtools:javac_jar"],
    javac_supports_workers = 1,
    jvm_opts = [
        "-XX:+TieredCompilation",
        "-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1",
    ],
    singlejar = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:SingleJar_deploy.jar"],
    source_version = "7",
    target_version = "7",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

And then build with:

```
bazel build --java_toolchain=//whatever:jdk7 //your:target
```